# slurm array job out of memory on second and subsequent tasks

Tags: slurm

I'm testing a SLURM job array with 5 tasks, before scaling up to run all 25000 tasks. Each task has an input file of 250 000 lines, and should output a file of the same 250 000 lines. The first task ran fine and output correctly, then all four subsequent tasks quit with "exceeded job memory" messages at around 2000 lines.
I tried increasing the memory allocation from 1M to 10M, then one task completed, another got to 200 000 lines, and the remaining three got to about 20 000 lines.
I thought each task should be running independently, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Have I missed something? Any comments greatly appreciated!

```
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --time=01:40:00
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=10M
#SBATCH --array=0-4
```

Here is the sacct output:

```
       JobID    JobName     MaxRSS    Elapsed 
------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- 
6746476_4    query.arr+              00:06:40 
6746476_4.b+      batch     30611K   00:06:41 
6746476_4.e+     extern       694K   00:06:40 
6746476_0    query.arr+              01:18:07 
6746476_0.b+      batch     31016K   01:18:08 
6746476_0.e+     extern       690K   01:18:07 
6746476_1    query.arr+              01:29:48 
6746476_1.b+      batch     30793K   01:29:48 
6746476_1.e+     extern       692K   01:29:48 
6746476_2    query.arr+              00:06:40 
6746476_2.b+      batch     31328K   00:06:45 
6746476_2.e+     extern       694K   00:06:40 
6746476_3    query.arr+              00:06:40 
6746476_3.b+      batch     30467K   00:06:43 
6746476_3.e+     extern       692K   00:06:40
```

Comment: The obvious would be to increase the memory request to at least 1GB.

Comment: yes this would probably get me through the 5 tasks, but what about the 25000? What I'm mostly after is why if one task works with the requested memory, why don't the others?